# Excel VBA Copy certain data down x row count

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, normally i would just resort to excel formulas.  I am writing a record database that extracts information from the users chosen excel sheet.  I have found code over the web that i have bodged together to get this: -

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", Filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen, Password:="uraduct")
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("B3:B11").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("B19:U162").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        OpenBook.Close False

End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
On Error Resume Next
Columns("K").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Basically, the B3:B11 is a title and i want it to appear on each row that is brought through on the B19:U162 which is either 1 column or 20 columns converted to rows (based on the delete at the end).

Also, in some cases the user has not filled in row/column 19 so if row/column 20 is filled i would like to add a default to row 19 to prevent it being overwrote on the next file upload.

I hope that makes sense.

Thank you,

Comment: The question says 'on the D19:U62' but the code says 'Range("B19:U162") ?

Comment: Good spot now amended :)

Comment: I have solved the first part of this with this code: -
Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(20, 0)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
Just need help on the second part now. 

Also, in some cases the user has not filled in row/column 19 so if row/column 20 is filled i would like to add a default to row 19 to prevent it being overwrote on the next file upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test cell("B19") and if empty calculate no of columns from row 20 then fill in the row. Close source workbook without saving changes.

```vb
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim cols As Integer
If OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("B19") = "" Then
    cols = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Cells(20, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("B19").Resize(1, cols).Value = "empty"
End If
OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("B19:U162").Copy
```

Comment: Really appreciate the response.  This doesnt seem to do what i am after.  But i believe i either havent explained it well and i may be entering your code wrong.

The data is extracted as columns and is then transposed as rows.  So what was in rows 19 (when the data is in columns) is then column J.  Rows 19 are usually completed by 5/6 of the users there is just one that is inconsistent.  If this is empty when it is transposed i would like it to say "empty" as per your code.

Comment: @Steven Insert the 5 lines from Dim cols to End If in your existing code before the Range("B19:U162").Copy.  It fills the missing row 19 which then gets transposed on paste into Column J.

Comment: I could do with it saying if column "k" <> "", and column "J"="", then column j = "empty" how can i add a few pictures so i can try and show how its displayed better.

Comment: Thank you soo much!!! That worked, i was deleting my code below and not inserting this as additional. Brilliant! :)